# Start Android APK with args from adb

Tags: android, adb, emulation, genymotion

I'm looking for way to start my APK with args.

First, How can I get args in `OnCreate` method?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //get args1, get  args2...
}
```

Then with adb, How can I run my application  with those args? I just see example like that:

```
adb shell am start -S -D com.example.apk/android.app.MainActivity --es args '"-name MYNAME -email test@gmail.com"'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, How can I get args in OnCreate method?

That is not possible, in the terms that you describe.

> Then with adb, How can I run my application with those args?

That is not possible, in the terms that you describe.

What you *can* do — and what the `adb` example shows you — is supply `Intent` extras:

```
adb shell am start -S -D com.example.apk/android.app.MainActivity --es args '"-name MYNAME -email test@gmail.com"'
```

This is not a particularly good way to use `Intent` extras, but let's start with it.

Here, you are passing a string extra named `args` with a value of `"-name MYNAME -email test@gmail.com"`.

In `onCreate()` of your activity, you could call `getIntent().getStringExtra("args")` to retrieve that string:

```
String args = getIntent().getStringExtra("args");
```

Now, the `args` variable will hold `-name MYNAME -email test@gmail.com`.

A simpler and cleaner `adb shell am start` command would be:

```
adb shell am start -S -D com.example.apk/android.app.MainActivity --es name MYNAME --es email test@gmail.com
```

Now you are passing two string extras, `name` and `email`. You can then retrieve each value individually:

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
String email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer doesn't work for me because -S(force stop) -D(debugging) is not enough to send extra value you should add -n(Component) for sending extra value with -e

here is the sample to sent multiple key-value

```
adb shell am start -n com.example.jk.checkwifi/.MainActivity -e "imei" $myimei -e "ip" $IP
```